# Transact sql: Delete one corresponding row in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a table similar to this:
timestamp, count, bunchOData

count is always 1 EXCEPT when someone makes a mistake and wants to remove an entry. The removals show up in the table as new, identical rows with count = -1. So:

```
timestamp            count  bunchOData
-------------------  -----  ----------
2017-05-31 13:42:16  1      stuff
2017-05-31 13:42:27  -1     stuff
```

I have to move the data into a new table where removals are simply deleted.
So, to migrate the data, I have to:
For each board with a count = -1, delete it and the single nearest (by time) board with identical bunchOData, and a count = 1

How do I do this efficiently?

EDITED: To make things somewhat clearer:

Here's a sample of what's in the table now:

```
DATE_TIME                   SPECIE_CODE LOAD                 LOAD_LIMIT           THICKNESS  GRADE_CODE                                         SURFACE_MEASURE                                    FBM                                                LOG_COUNT
--------------------------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
2016-12-01 10:40:46         ASH         850-OHP              15000                4/4        Sel                                                13                                                 13                                                 1
2016-12-01 10:40:52         ASH         850-OHP              15000                4/4        Sel                                                -13                                                -13                                                -1
2016-12-01 10:48:32         ASH         850-OHP              15000                4/4        Sel                                                6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:48:43         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:48:51         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Sel S                                              5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:48:59         ASH         850-EMPIRE           500                  4/4        2&3Com                                             6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:49:47         ASH         850-BSI2             10000000             6/4        1Com                                               5                                                  7.5                                                1
2016-12-01 10:49:56         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                5                                                  7.5                                                1
2016-12-01 10:50:03         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        1Com                                               10                                                 10                                                 1
2016-12-01 10:50:20         ASH         850-EMPIRE           500                  4/4        2&3Com                                             10                                                 10                                                 1
2016-12-01 10:50:27         ASH         850-EMPIRE           500                  4/4        2&3Com                                             5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:50:36         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Sel S                                              6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:50:47         ASH         850-EMPIRE           500                  4/4        2&3Com                                             10                                                 10                                                 1
2016-12-01 10:52:10         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Frm                                                5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:52:21         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Frm                                                6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:52:26         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Frm                                                5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:52:39         ASH         850-BSI2             10000000             6/4        1Com                                               10                                                 15                                                 1
2016-12-01 10:52:48         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:52:54         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:53:00         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:53:06         ASH         850-OHP              15000                4/4        Sel                                                5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:55:31         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:59:30         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:59:37         ASH         850-OHP              15000                4/4        Sel                                                6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:59:48         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                5                                                  7.5                                                1
2016-12-01 10:59:54         ASH         850-BSI2             10000000             6/4        1Com                                               10                                                 15                                                 1
2016-12-01 11:00:08         ASH         850-BSI2             10000000             6/4        1Com                                               -10                                                -15                                                -1
2016-12-01 11:00:20         ASH         850-BSI2             10000000             6/4        1Com                                               10                                                 15                                                 1
2016-12-01 11:01:02         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
```

I would like to remove the entries with '-1' for log_count, and the corresponding entries with '1' for log count that precede (but may not IMMEDIATELY precede) them. Like this:

```
DATE_TIME                   SPECIE_CODE LOAD                 LOAD_LIMIT           THICKNESS  GRADE_CODE                                         SURFACE_MEASURE                                    FBM                                                LOG_COUNT
--------------------------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
2016-12-01 10:48:32         ASH         850-OHP              15000                4/4        Sel                                                6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:48:43         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:48:51         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Sel S                                              5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:48:59         ASH         850-EMPIRE           500                  4/4        2&3Com                                             6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:49:47         ASH         850-BSI2             10000000             6/4        1Com                                               5                                                  7.5                                                1
2016-12-01 10:49:56         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                5                                                  7.5                                                1
2016-12-01 10:50:03         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        1Com                                               10                                                 10                                                 1
2016-12-01 10:50:20         ASH         850-EMPIRE           500                  4/4        2&3Com                                             10                                                 10                                                 1
2016-12-01 10:50:27         ASH         850-EMPIRE           500                  4/4        2&3Com                                             5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:50:36         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Sel S                                              6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:50:47         ASH         850-EMPIRE           500                  4/4        2&3Com                                             10                                                 10                                                 1
2016-12-01 10:52:10         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Frm                                                5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:52:21         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Frm                                                6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:52:26         ASH         850-BSI1             10000000             4/4        Frm                                                5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:52:39         ASH         850-BSI2             10000000             6/4        1Com                                               10                                                 15                                                 1
2016-12-01 10:52:48         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:52:54         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:53:00         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:53:06         ASH         850-OHP              15000                4/4        Sel                                                5                                                  5                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:55:31         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:59:30         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:59:37         ASH         850-OHP              15000                4/4        Sel                                                6                                                  6                                                  1
2016-12-01 10:59:48         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                5                                                  7.5                                                1
2016-12-01 11:00:20         ASH         850-BSI2             10000000             6/4        1Com                                               10                                                 15                                                 1
2016-12-01 11:01:02         ASH         850-BSI3             10000000             6/4        Stb                                                6                                                  9                                                  1
```

Comment: There just isn't enough information here to provide a very solid answer. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Out of interest, why do you have it work like that? Seems open for error.

Comment: There is something confusing in your question. In one hand you say that you want removals simply deleted, but later you add that they must have close date as well. Is this close date condition necessary?

Comment: @Leonidas: The only answer I have for you is the magic word, "Legacy."

Comment: @TheEsisia: Sorry if that was confusing. Deleting the removals is easy, but I also want to delete the original entry that the '-1' record is meant to undo.

Answer (score 0):

This is all very doable, but what would make it much, much easier is if you had a unique key in your source table.  This way you would have some sort of handle to throw around.

I would suggest that because this is data migration, and probably a one-off/ problematic task, that you consider breaking it down into steps.  I'm not going to give you working SQL, as I don't have enough information from your question to do so, but this is how I would start:

- make a list of cases where [count] = -1, as these are all the cancellations you need to match up and remove;
- ideally this would be a list of unique keys to the table being processed, stored as a temporary (or even permanent) table;
- from this list you would find the matching record to be deleted, using a windowed function (e.g. ROW_NUMBER()) to pick the best match, where there are multiple matches, based on the timestamp being the most recent;
- some cancellations might not have a match, so you would put these to one side and investigate them manually;
- there might even be cases with duplicate matches (exact same timestamp), which you would again need to investigate;
- the remaining matches will essentially be two lists now, a list of unique keys for the cancellations, and a second list of the same size for the rows being cancelled;
- delete all of these rows, or flag them to not be migrated somehow.

If you don't have any unique key to the table then I would even consider creating one, on a temporary basis, as it makes this so much easier.  You could do this with something like:

```
SELECT NEWID() AS temp_key, * INTO [workingTable] FROM [myTable];
```

Do all your work on that working table, then migrate the data from there, removing the now-redundant key in the process.

---

Okay, now we have data I can show you how this might work in real life.

First job is to load your data into a temporary table, so I can play with it:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--This is the source data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#source') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #source;
CREATE TABLE #source (
    DATE_TIME DATETIME,
    SPECIE_CODE VARCHAR(3),
    [LOAD] VARCHAR(25),
    LOAD_LIMIT INT,
    THICKNESS VARCHAR(4),
    GRADE_CODE VARCHAR(20),
    SURFACE_MEASURE INT,
    FBM INT,
    LOG_COUNT INT);
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:40:46', 'ASH', '850-OHP', 15000, '4/4', 'Sel', 13, 13, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:40:52', 'ASH', '850-OHP', 15000, '4/4', 'Sel', -13, -13, -1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:48:32', 'ASH', '850-OHP', 15000, '4/4', 'Sel', 6, 6, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:48:43', 'ASH', '850-BSI3', 10000000, '6/4', 'Stb', 6, 9, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:48:51', 'ASH', '850-BSI1', 10000000, '4/4', 'Sel S', 5, 5, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:48:59', 'ASH', '850-EMPIRE', 500, '4/4', '2&3Com', 6, 6, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:49:47', 'ASH', '850-BSI2', 10000000, '6/4', '1Com', 5, 7.5, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:49:56', 'ASH', '850-BSI3', 10000000, '6/4', 'Stb', 5, 7.5, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:50:03', 'ASH', '850-BSI1', 10000000, '4/4', '1Com', 10, 10, 1
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:50:20', 'ASH', '850-EMPIRE', 500, '4/4', '2&3Com', 10, 10, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:50:27', 'ASH', '850-EMPIRE', 500, '4/4', '2&3Com', 5, 5, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:50:36', 'ASH', '850-BSI1', 10000000, '4/4', 'Sel S', 6, 6, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:50:47', 'ASH', '850-EMPIRE', 500, '4/4', '2&3Com', 10, 10, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:52:10', 'ASH', '850-BSI1', 10000000, '4/4', 'Frm', 5, 5, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:52:21', 'ASH', '850-BSI1', 10000000, '4/4', 'Frm', 6, 6, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:52:26', 'ASH', '850-BSI1', 10000000, '4/4', 'Frm', 5, 5, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:52:39', 'ASH', '850-BSI2', 10000000, '6/4', '1Com', 10, 15, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:52:48', 'ASH', '850-BSI3', 10000000, '6/4', 'Stb', 6, 9, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:52:54', 'ASH', '850-BSI3', 10000000, '6/4', 'Stb', 6, 9, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:53:00', 'ASH', '850-BSI3', 10000000, '6/4', 'Stb', 6, 9, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:53:06', 'ASH', '850-OHP', 15000, '4/4', 'Sel', 5, 5, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:55:31', 'ASH', '850-BSI3', 10000000, '6/4', 'Stb', 6, 9, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:59:30', 'ASH', '850-BSI3', 10000000, '6/4', 'Stb', 6, 9, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:59:37', 'ASH', '850-OHP', 15000, '4/4', 'Sel', 6, 6, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:59:48', 'ASH', '850-BSI3', 10000000, '6/4', 'Stb', 5, 7.5, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 10:59:54', 'ASH', '850-BSI2', 10000000, '6/4', '1Com', 10, 15, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 11:00:08', 'ASH', '850-BSI2', 10000000, '6/4', '1Com', -10, -15, -1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 11:00:20', 'ASH', '850-BSI2', 10000000, '6/4', '1Com', 10, 15, 1;
INSERT INTO #source SELECT '2016-12-01 11:01:02', 'ASH', '850-BSI3', 10000000, '6/4', 'Stb', 6, 9, 1;
```

So now I have 29 rows of data to be processed.  The next job is to identify cancellations:

```
--Assuming that the timestamp is unique, make a list of cancelled items
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#cancelled') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #cancelled;
SELECT *, CONVERT(DATETIME, NULL) AS MATCHED_DATE_TIME INTO #cancelled FROM #source WHERE LOG_COUNT = -1;
```

That will give me a list of two cancellations to identify, match up, and remove.  This is how I do this:

```
--Attempt to find matches
WITH BestMatch AS (
    SELECT
        c.*,
        s.DATE_TIME AS CANDIDATE_MATCHED_DATE_TIME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.DATE_TIME ORDER BY s.DATE_TIME DESC) AS MATCH_ID
    FROM
        #cancelled c
        INNER JOIN #source s ON s.DATE_TIME <= c.DATE_TIME AND s.SPECIE_CODE = c.SPECIE_CODE AND s.[LOAD] = c.[LOAD] AND s.LOAD_LIMIT = c.LOAD_LIMIT
            AND s.THICKNESS = c.THICKNESS AND s.GRADE_CODE = c.GRADE_CODE AND s.SURFACE_MEASURE = c.SURFACE_MEASURE * -1 AND s.FBM = c.FBM * -1)
UPDATE
    c
SET
    MATCHED_DATE_TIME = bm.CANDIDATE_MATCHED_DATE_TIME
FROM
    BestMatch bm
    INNER JOIN #cancelled c ON c.DATE_TIME = bm.DATE_TIME
WHERE
    bm.MATCH_ID = 1; --Only pick the latest match
```

When I run this it finds the best match for each cancelled item, using date order to pick the best option where there are multiple candidates.  If I were to SELECT the results of the CTE (BestMatch) then I would see how this works:

```
DATE_TIME   SPECIE_CODE LOAD    LOAD_LIMIT  THICKNESS   GRADE_CODE  SURFACE_MEASURE FBM LOG_COUNT   MATCHED_DATE_TIME   CANDIDATE_MATCHED_DATE_TIME MATCH_ID
2016-12-01 10:40:52.000 ASH 850-OHP 15000   4/4 Sel -13 -13 -1  NULL    2016-12-01 10:40:46.000 1
2016-12-01 11:00:08.000 ASH 850-BSI2    10000000    6/4 1Com    -10 -15 -1  NULL    2016-12-01 10:59:54.000 1
2016-12-01 11:00:08.000 ASH 850-BSI2    10000000    6/4 1Com    -10 -15 -1  NULL    2016-12-01 10:52:39.000 2
```

The first cancellation is for a row with a LOAD value of 850-OHP, and there is only one candidate here, so no problem.  The second cancellation is for a row with a LOAD value of 850-BS12, and this time there are two potential matches.  We order these and assign each one a MATCH_ID that will start at 1 and increment by 1 for each subsequent match.  The MATCH_ID is in date time order, so the row with a MATCH_ID of 1 (10:59:54) is the one we want to remove, and the row with a MATCH_ID of 2 (10:52:39) is to be left intact.

You should probably check for any issues at this point:

```
--Investigate any issues
SELECT * FROM #cancelled WHERE MATCHED_DATE_TIME IS NULL;
```

But there aren't any so we carry on to perform the delete:

```
--Perform the delete
DELETE FROM #source WHERE LOG_COUNT = -1;
DELETE s FROM #source s INNER JOIN #cancelled c ON c.MATCHED_DATE_TIME = s.DATE_TIME;
```

On completion there are 25 rows remaining:

```
--Show the results
SELECT * FROM #source;
```

Comment: Thanks, Richard. The difficulty comes with your 3rd bullet point. I've added some real data in an edit to my post that may illustrate my problem better.

Answer (score 0):

First, get a list of all SPECIE_CODE, LOAD, LOAD_LIMIT and THICKNESS values that have appeared with count = -1 in your table. These are all the removals' SPECIE_CODE, LOAD, LOAD_LIMIT and THICKNESS values. Then delete all rows with such values. It will remove all of those regardless of their count value:

```
delete from MyTable 
Where SPECIE_CODE + LOAD + LOAD_LIMIT + THICKNESS + GRADE_CODE 
     in (select SPECIE_CODE + LOAD + LOAD_LIMIT + THICKNESS + GRADE_CODE from @MyTable where counts = -1)
```

Comment: Ah. I only want to remove ONE of the entries that match, not all of them.